# Changing from x to y $x = y(4-y)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$x = y(4-y)$$

I am guessing I need some pretty advanced math to solve this for y. I am trying to use the shell method and I have to use opposite terms of the rotation axis so I am rotating around y so I need x variables.

I have a whole sheet of paper trying to solve this, is there any easy way?

Comment: Are you required to use the shell method? Doing it this way would require splitting into two integrals. The washer method would be far easier to compute.

Comment: Yes I have to use the shell method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
y^2 - 4y & = -x. \\[8pt]
y^2 - 4y + 4 & = -x + 4 \qquad = 4-x. \\[8pt]
(y-2)^2 & = 4-x. \\[8pt]
y-2 & = \pm\sqrt{4-x} \\[8pt]
y & = 2\pm\sqrt{4-x}.
\end{align}

This leaves a question: How did we know that $4$ is what had to be added to both sides to get a square?  Google the term "completeing the square".  Then bring any questions back here.

Comment: Is there any easy method to memorizing completing the square? I use to have something memorized where I could basically look at a term and get it.

Comment: @PaulthePirate Don't memorize it, understand it. Then you can reconstruct it in seconds every time you need it.

Comment: I do understand it sort of, but I always forget the understanding. I have learned it dozens of times over the years but when I only use it a couple times a year it is hard to remember. I would prefer to just memorize it before a test than learn to understand it every week for the rest of my life.

Comment: You probably are cursed with a good memory, and have been using the strategy of memorizing not understanding for a long time. In the long run it doesn't work.

Comment: To understand completing the square, you need to know that $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$.  If you have something like $w^2+12w$, then $w^2$ is $a^2$ and $12w$ is $2ab$.  Since $12w$ is $2ab$, you get $b=6$.  Thus $b^2=6^2$.  So $w^2+12w+36$ is the complete square, equal to $(w+6)^2$.  That's completing the square.  If you submit your question in your comment as a "question", maybe you'll get some more extensive answers.

Answer (score 0):

You know that points on this curve satisfy $y^2 - 4y + x = 0$.  Apply the quadratic formula for $y$ to get $$
\begin{align}
y & = \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{(-4)^2 - 4(1)(x)}}{2(1)} \\
& = 2 \pm \sqrt{4-x}
\end{align}
$$

This is the same thing as "completing the square", the quadratic formula is just a computational shortcut.